# Binding Button-Visibility in Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

i've defined an initial Table with three rows and 9 Column in Datagrid. right now  button should be visible only if i select a row and then press another button that i defined in my Ribbon-Tab after that my Button will be Visible. sofar everything works well, but the Problem is after saving my Table, closing it and open the Table again the button is not there anymore. I set the Visibility based on if the DataGridCell.IsSelected, also a BooleanToVisibilityConverter to convert the boolean value to a Visibility one.
can anyone help!

XAML:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
   <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter" />
</DataGrid.Resources>
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="subgraphtyp" Header="H." Width="50">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <Button Name="btnTable" Visibility="{Binding Path=Hinterlegung, Converter=  
               {StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}"  Height="20" Width="25" 
               Click="Button_Table_Click">
         <Image Height="16" Source="Subgraph.png" Stretch="Fill" Width="16"/>
       </Button>
     </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

C#:
    public bool Hinterlegung { get; set; }

```
private void Button_StartTableModus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (DataGrid1.SelectedItem != null && tabItem1.IsSelected)
  {
    TableDataRowStringItem item = (TableDataRowStringItem)DataGrid1.CurrentItem;
    string wert = item.ObjectType;
    string rowName = item.Name;
    if (wert == "Function" || wert == "Process")
    {
      item.Hinterlegung = true;
      if (!tabControl.Items.Contains(tabItem2))
      {
        tabControl.Items.Add(tabItem2);
        tabItem2.Focus();
        tabItem2.IsSelected = true;
        tabItem2.Header = rowName;
        TableTab.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        openTabs++;
        DataGrid2.IsReadOnly = false;

        starting_Table_Mod_at_start2V();
      }
    }
  }
}

//this my initial Table
private ObservableCollection<TableDataRowStringItem> tableobject = new      
ObservableCollection<TableDataRowStringItem>();

private void starting_Table_Mod_at_start2V()
{
  List<TableDataRowStringItem> rowstringList = new List<TableDataRowStringItem>();
  TableDataRowStringItem item = new TableDataRowStringItem();
  item.RowNumber = 1; item.saveFlag = true; item.ObjectType = "E"; item.Name = "E"; 
  item.PredecessorRowNumber = "0"; rowstringList.Add(item);
  item = new TableDataRowStringItem();
  item.RowNumber = 2; item.ObjectType = "Function"; item.Name = "Function";       
  item.PredecessorRowNumber = "1"; rowstringList.Add(item);
  item = new TableDataRowStringItem();
  item.RowNumber = 3; item.ObjectType = "E"; item.Name = "E";   
  item.PredecessorRowNumber = "2"; rowstringList.Add(item);


  for (int i = 0; i < rowstringList.Count; i++)
  {
    tableobject.Add(rowstringList[i]); 
  }
  DataGrid2.ItemsSource = tableobject;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button's visibility is bound to your Hinterlegung variable which has a default value of false.  So as best as I can tell, you change it to true in this method -  Button_StartTableModus. But, when you reinitialize, the value reverts to false, so you need to set it to true.

Comment: its written there in this Method that item.Hinterlegung = true;

Comment: @H79  Your set it in this method Button_StartTableModus, right?  Is this the method that gets called when the button is clicked?

Comment: the Button in my Ribbon-Tab not the one for my Table

Comment: @H79  Okay, so the ribbon's button click event is setting item.Hinterlegung = true.  When you reload the table, how are you setting the value of item.Hinterlegung?  Or are you?

Comment: i didnt set any value of item.Hinterlegung

Comment: @H79  Okay, so I'm guessing that item.Hinterlegung's value is false at this point.  Can you verify?

Comment: @H79 So there's your answer. You'll need to persist item.Hinterlegung = true, so it retains it state when the table reloads. Then, your button will be visible.

Comment: @H79  Good and please mark as Answered if it solved your issue.